# In SQL: add a column based on before or after date?

Tags: sql, oracle

In Oracle SQL Developer, how do I *add* a column based on whether my date column has a value before or after January 1st, 2010?

For example:

```
Date
---------
01-JAN-10
01-JUL-15
07-JAN-07
```

I would like to see it like this:

```
Date        on_time
--------------------
01-JAN-10      N
01-JUL-15      Y
07-JAN-07      N
```

Where `N` means the value is equal to or later in time than: January 1st, 2010

and `Y` means the value is before January 1st, 2010.

Is this even possible to do? I have not added a new column in SQL before.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `CASE` statement for this:

```
SELECT your_date, 
CASE WHEN your_date > '2010-01-01' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N'  END "on_time"
FROM your_table
```

It checks if the date is greater than `2010-01-01` then it will print `Y` else it will print `N`

Comment: Just to add on to this answer, if you wanted to be very specific you could specify the date format, just in case the NLS settings aren't what you'd expect; `to_date('2010-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')`

Comment: Unlike Adam's answer, this still doesn't address half of what the OP asked  -  he asked also how to add a column, not just what expression to use.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [Case](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems004.htm) Statement based on the date column.
For example:

```
CASE WHEN [your date column] > '01-JAN-10' THEN 'N'
ELSE 'Y'
END
```

Of course make sure you use the PL/SQL to_date function for string conversion

Comment: I have angular brackets in my Answer, and the posting engine perceived that as a tag and did not display my Answer correctly.

Comment: You don't compare a date to a string. Silly Oracle will do some conversions for you, instead of telling you that you have a data type mismatch. Anyway, which do you think is earlier, if you compare them AS STINGS: `01-JAN-10` or `12-MAR-08`? Is that the right answer (for dates)? Otherwise, you are taking a chance that Oracle will convert the string to a date, not the other way around - and that the NLS settings will be EXACTLY `'dd-MON-rr'`. Good luck with that!

Comment: @mathguy, that's why I stated: "Of course make sure you use the PL/SQL to_date function for string conversion"

Answer (score 0):

you can use virtual column:

```
alter table <table_name>
add (<column_name> [<data_type>] [generated always] as (<column_expression>) [virtual]);
```

so, you can use `case` function to generate your column:

```
CASE WHEN Date > to_date('2010-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd') THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END
```

Comment: Hi @Adam Silenko, I'm new to this - where in my query would I add 'alter table' and 'add' and then later 'CASE WHEN' ? My query has SELECT, FROM, LEFT JOIN, and WHERE statements. Not sure where this fits in yet.

Comment: you can `add column` to your `table`, and then use it in `SELECT` clause like normal column, or use this expression directly in `SELECT`